# Unable to launch Chromium edge browser using codeceptjs

Tags: webdriver, codeceptjs, microsoft-edge-chromium

I'm trying to launch Chromium edge browser using codeceptjs framework. I'm new to codeceptjs. My scripts are running fine with Chrome and Firefox browsers but, getting following error with Chromium edge.

```
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "edge",
    "ms:edgeChromium": true,
    "platformName": "windows",
    "browserVersion": "88.0.705.81"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "edge",
        "browserVersion": "88.0.705.81",
        "ms:edgeChromium": true,
        "platformName": "windows"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'XXX', ip: 'YYY', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', 
java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Please make sure Selenium Server (ChromeDriver or PhantomJS) is running and accessible

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think browser name should be MicrosoftEdge. At least it's working such way using Selenoid

Comment: Thanks a lot Vitalii Sotnichenko.. It worked. I tried different names for it.. msedge, microsoftedge, edge, etc. But didn't realize the case for MicrosoftEdge..